# deploying React js with router and without server

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm writing a web content website with React and I'm using React router dom for routing. I want to deploy my website but I need to know if I have to buy a node js host or a regular host. After searching figured out that if I use Hashrouter instead of Browserrouter, I can deploy it without server but there is a problem because hashrouter adds a prefix # on all of my links. What should I do to remove # or is there any other solution?

Comment: if ur app does not relying on backend then u dont need a nodejs hosting. you can host it by running build script which generates static files in build folder, and then host it in platforms like firebase hosting

Comment: @wadecodes my code doesn't rely on backend but if I use BrowserRouter, after build I only get a blank page